# Default variance estimators in Stata for ivregress

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables

Using Stata, why are the default variance estimators in `ivregress 2sls` so different from `reg`?

1. With classical standard errors, `ivregress 2sls` doesn't apply the finite sample correction `(N / (N-k))` and uses z-tests unless you specify the `small` option. If you specify `small`, it applies the standard correction and uses t-tests?
2. With robust standard errors, one has to apply `small` to move from HC0 w/ z-tests to HC1 w/ t-tests (which is the default with `reg`).
3. With clusters, again one has to apply `small` to get the `(N-1)/(N-k) * M/(M-1)` correction that is default in `reg`.

Is there any justification for the difference in defaults across the two estimators? Why would we prefer finite sample corrections in OLS but not 2SLS?

I've also asked [on the statalist forum](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1430978-why-is-%60small%60-not-the-default-in-%60ivregress%60).

Comment: This seems like a good statistical question about finite sample corrections, even if it seems like software-specific question at first glance.

Comment: I agree. As far as I can tell, the literature isn't clear about what is most appropriate, although I would think that conservative estimates would in general have better finite-sample performance.

Comment: Is there any news/updates on this question?

Comment: Only the one response in the linked stataist post that discusses question #2.